# Grabbing values between anchors

Tags: javascript

have to grab some values between anchors:
Here is the code:

```
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>

    <li class="">

            <a href="http://viewpoint.com/about">About</a>

    </li>

    <li class="">

            <a href="http://viewpoint.com/about/news">News</a>

    </li>

    <li class=" first last active">
        details
    </li>
```

I need to get (Home, About, News) or of the text above.
I am grabbing this from a site for a client, i do not have access to change the main HTML to insert an id or class name.  Also, sometimes there could be 1 anchor, maybe 5, depending on the sites breadcrumb

Comment: It's this what jQuery was born for?

Comment: jQuery: `$("li a")`. That simple.

Comment: @JCOC611: i have a sneaking suspicion that would over-match in the whole document...

Comment: @dandavis: With the information the OP provided us, it is impossible to make a more specific selector.

Comment: @JCOC611: "li>a[href]" is more specific; a lot of folks use LI for content...

Answer (score 1):

Pure javascript:

```
links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i=0; i < links.length; i++) { 
    console.log(links[i].innerHTML); 
}
```

with jQuery:

```
$('a').each(function() { 
    console.log($(this).text()); 
});
```

More specifically:

```
$('li a').each(function() {....});
```